# Where do I get the list of ColumnAttribute.TypeName possible values for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ef-code-first, columnmappings

I'm using Entity Framework code-first. When mapping class properties to Oracle database table columns I do the following:

```
public class Employee{
   [Column("EMPLOYEEID")]
   public int EmployeeID{get;set;}
}
```

I've noticed that I can also specify the column type with the help of TypeName named parameter. But I have no idea where I can get the list of possible values. In the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute.typename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it just says:

`The database provider specific data type of the column the property is mapped to.` And that's it. I see people passing varchar,int but I wonder where they get those values. Right now I need to map a property of type `long` to the corresponding column but don't know what to set the TypeName to. I've tried Int64, but I get runtime exception about incompatibility of database and entity framework types.

Comment: An Oracle 'LONG' is not a numeric type. It was Oracle's first attempt at a LOB (Large Object) type. I don't know if this will help but [the Oracle ADO.NET datatype mapping docs can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featLINQ.htm). This was the first hit when Googling for "code-first entity framework Oracle data type mapping". Best of luck.

Comment: I know that Long is not a numeric type. I meant long in .net not in Oracle. In Oracle I have a column of type number(12,0). So the number corresponding to it in .net would be Int64 or long in other words. Thanks for the link. You won't believe but I've been excavating the net for 2 days now for such a possibly helpful documentation.

Comment: If Int64 doesn't work them try mapping it to Decimal, and if *that* fails try mapping to String. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried Float and Varchar2. With float, the generated query casts the Int64 property to number(19,0). With VARCHAR2 I get runtime exception complaining the the types are not compatible. DO you have any idea why I just cannot use TypeName="Number(12,0)". When I do so, the I get exception that `The Type number(12,0) is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.` What namespace should I qualify it with?

Comment: What happens if you try "NUMBER", without precision/scale?

Comment: It works, but the CAST is still applied to the query

Comment: Well, clearly it's not going to allow "NUMBER(12,0)" as that's not a primitive type (in its opinion). What happens if you change `EmployeeID` to return `Decimal` instead of `int`?